# Change the background color of the console with the help of enum

Tags: c#, beginner, console, enum

I've recently learned the concept of `enum` and method calling with the `enum`. From what I learned I've done this simple snippet which changes the background color of the console with the help of enum and method.

```
    public static void SetColor(RanngDe R){
        switch (R){
            case RanngDe.Blue:
                 Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                 break;

            case RanngDe.Green:
                 Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                 break;
            default:
                 Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                 break;
        }   
    }

// Enum Declaration
public enum RanngDe{
    Blue=0,
    Green=1,
    Yellow=3
}
```

I'm calling `RanngDe` method in the main method in `switch ...case` block as menu driven. I know, I've used `switch ...case` in `void SetColor(RanngDe R)` method, which is my **major** concern, because this makes my code **redundant** as I'm calling it in the menu driven program.

Is this approach acceptable as good practice? If not then, how should I make this better?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the program it is hard to say, but an alternate method would be to use a dictionary which would remove the switch statement and make it a simple assignment statement.

Comment: Why not use `ConsoleColor` directly, instead of creating a `RanngDe` enum? Is it really important to limit the parameter to those three colors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been mentioned using a `Dictionary<RanngDe,Color>` will make your code much simpler:

```
public enum RanngDe
{
    Blue = 0,
    Green = 1,
    Yellow = 3
}
static Dictionary<RanngDe, ConsoleColor> colors = new Dictionary<RanngDe, ConsoleColor>()
{
    {RanngDe.Blue,ConsoleColor.Blue },
    {RanngDe.Green,ConsoleColor.Green },
    {RanngDe.Yellow,ConsoleColor.Yellow }
};
public static void SetColor(RanngDe R)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = colors[R];
}
```

Depending on your implementation you might be able to do away with the method completely and just use the assignment.

I came up with another approach.  If you change the values of `Ranngde` to be the same as the `ConsoleColor` enum, you can cast the `Ranngde` value to `ConsoleColor`:

```
public enum RanngDe
{
    Blue = ConsoleColor.Blue,
    Green = ConsoleColor.Green,
    Yellow = ConsoleColor.Yellow
}
public static void SetColor(RanngDe R)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)R;
}
```

Comment: It would be even nicer if you defined the enum values as `Blue = ConsoleColor.Blue` instead of using magic numbers.

Comment: Yep.  It is done